# How to concatenate url in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, multidimensional-array

```
"questionnaire": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "status": "1",
            "name": "Driniking water 24h",
            "lang_id": 2,
            "zona_id": 7,
            "created_at": "2019-05-07 10:35:18",
            "updated_at": "2019-06-01 10:01:08",
            "questionnaire_category": 1,
            "question_number": 1,
            "content": "Driniking water  Driniking water  Driniking water  Driniking water"
        }
    ],
 "next": {
        "id": 7,
        "status": "1",
        "name": "Public Lighting",
        "lang_id": 1,
        "zona_id": 7,
        "created_at": "2019-05-22 05:04:27",
        "updated_at": "2019-06-01 10:00:37",
        "questionnaire_category": 1,
        "question_number": 2,
        "content": "Public Lighting Public Lighting Public Lighting Public Lighting"
    }
```

I have to concatenate the id of questionnaire with id of next, this is my url https://quiet-cove-41253.herokuapp.com/api/questionApi/1 , i don`t know how to concatenate these two id?????

```
var response = await fetch(`https://quiet-cove-41253.herokuapp.com/api/questionApi/1/6`+this.state.nextData.id);
```

```
state = {
    data: [],
    nextData: []
  };

fetchData = async () => {
    var response = await fetch(`https://quiet-cove-41253.herokuapp.com/api/questionApi/1/6`+this.state.nextData.id);
    var json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ data: json.questionnaire, nextData: json.next });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

render(){
return(
<View><Text>{this.state.data.id}</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.data.name}</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.data.content}</Text>
</View>
)
}
```

My point is that from the **next id** my questions will change

Comment: did you tried like this `https://quiet-cove-41253.herokuapp.com/api/questionApi/1/6${this.state.nextData.id}`

Comment: Is showing only the **nextData id**, can I add the **questionnaire id** as well in the url

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
var response = await fetch(`https://quiet-cove-41253.herokuapp.com/api/questionApi/1/6,${this.state.nextData.id}`);
```

Comment: Now I can get both of them but the question is not changing

Comment: you need to pass question_id also dynamically as 6 is being passed it will always be 6

Comment: But I dont know how?

Comment: you should store the question_id in state also and pass ```${this.state.question_id}``` instead of 6